# How to select rows that contain only a single value

Tags: sql-server, row

I have 2 tables in Sql (EqmType and Equipment)
An equipment can only have 1 eqmtype. An eqmtype can have multiple equipments.

EqmType
  - EqmtId
  - EqmtDescr

Equipment
  - EqmId
  - EqmEqmtId (foreign key to EqmType)
  - Eqmrecstatus (value 2 is active, 8 is missing, 16 is ToDelete,...)

The output needs to be a list of all the rows in EqmType that contain only equipments with value of eqmrecstatus being equal to 16.

for example:
An eqmtype has 10 equipments. 9 of them have 16 as value for eqmrecstatus and 1 has 2 => not in resultlist
An eqmtype has 10 equipments. all 10 have 16 as value for eqmrecstatus => in resultlist

If not clear, let me know :)

Comment: Use joins for this purpose. Please try before you post questions. A little search won't do any harm. It will only benefit you in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `NOT EXISTS` is what you need here:

```
SELECT  et.EqmtId, et.EqmtDescr
FROM    EqmType AS et
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Equipment AS e
            WHERE   e.EqmEqmtId = et.EqmtId
            AND     e.Eqmrecstatus != 16
        );
```

You are essentially getting all equipments that have a status that is not 16:

```
SELECT  e.EqmEqmtId
FROM    Equipment AS e
```

Then you are removing these results from the main select. Possibly a more intuitive way of writing this is:

```
SELECT  et.EqmtId, et.EqmtDescr
FROM    EqmType AS et
WHERE   et.EqmtId NOT IN (SELECT e.EqmEqmtId FROM Equipment AS e WHERE e.Eqmrecstatus != 16);
```

But `NOT EXISTS` is a safer option.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the join on the both the tables and then apply the filter using `where` clause. But it is `1-n` relation so you might want to apply the `Distinct` as you just need the data from the `EqmType` table.[Read more about join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
  Select DISTINCT e.EqmtId,e.EqmtDescr
  FROM EqmType e join Equipment eq
       ON e.EqmtId = eq.EqmtId 
  WHERE eq.Eqmrecstatus = 16
```